# use addwitnessaddress outside bitcoin core's wallet. Are there any libraries?

Tags: segregated-witness

I want to create P2SH of witness script. I know bitcoin core has addwitnessaddress rpc method but I want to use it for addresses which are outside bitcoin core's wallet. I tried to find the tools on github but I couldn't find it. I think I can create it. Before that I want to ask you whether the libraries already exist or not.

---

Update 1

Seems NBitcoin has the feature.

- English

https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain/content/other_types_of_ownership/p2w_over_p2sh.html

- Japanese

https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain-japanese/content/other_types_of_ownership/p2w_over_p2sh.html